# Is this "automatic parallelism" exception-safe?

Tags: haskell, exception, parallel-processing

I tried to implement some kind of automatic parallelism in Haskell. My idea is:

1. Get current capability of parallelism. (Initially, this is the number of processors.)
2. When a task A is asked to run in parallel to task B:

- If the capabilitiy is 1, execute A and B sequentially.
- Otherwise, reduce the capability by 1, then execute A in parallel to B. When A is finished, increment the capability by 1.

I implemented this idea like:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception

pForkIO :: IO a -> IO a
pForkIO action = do
    cap <- getNumCapabilities
    if (1 == cap)
        then action
        else runInBoundThread (bracket_ (setNumCapabilities (cap - 1)) (do {cap2 <- getNumCapabilities; setNumCapabilities (cap2 + 1)}) action)
```

An example of usage of `pForkIO`:

```
import Data.List

pFoldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> IO m
pFoldMap f xs = go f xs (length xs) where
    go _ [] _ = mempty
    go f [x] _ = return (f x)
    go f xs n = do
        let halfN = quot n 2
        let (us,vs) = splitAt halfN xs
        m1 <- pForkIO (go f us halfN)
        m2 <- go f vs (n - halfN)
        return (m1 <> m2)
```

To deal with exceptions, I used `bracket_`. Is `pForkIO` really exception-safe yet?

(Btw, for unknown reason, `getNumCapabilities` initially returns 1 despite my machine having 8 processors. This should be another question...)

**EDIT:** Yes, I know, the `pFoldMap` above has worse complexity than plain `foldMap`, but let's focus on `pForkIO` for now...

Answer (score 2):

This won't work the way you are intending.

First, the `getNumCapabilities`/`setNumCapabilities` functions don't manage a count of unused capabilities that you can "allocate" manually this way.  Rather, they basically get and set the current setting for the `-N` runtime argument, which specifies the total number of simultaneously CPU-runnable threads that will run Haskell code, as managed by the runtime system.  If you use `setNumCapabilities` to reduce the number of capabilities, you are merely *reducing* the number of threads (bound or not) that will actually run in parallel.

Second, `runInBoundThread` doesn't fork a thread in parallel, it just ensures that an operation is run within a bound thread.  If this requires creation of a new bound thread, the operation will still be run sequentially with the call blocking until the operation completes.

If you want to fork and run in parallel a number of bound threads only up to the number of capabilities, you will need to separately manage a copy of the capabilities count (e.g., with an `MVar`), initialized by the value from `getNumCapabilities`, but you shouldn't use `setNumCapabilities` at all.  And, you'll need to use `forkOS` (which forks a bound thread) in place of `runInBoundThread`.

Generally speaking, though, I don't think there's any point in doing this.  The runtime system already contains support for running a set of IO threads in parallel using `forkIO`, and it will run up to `getNumCapabilities` of them simultaneously on separate cores.  It is largely counterproductive to use bound threads except when they are needed for using a foreign API that manages thread-local state; and it is usually counterproductive to limit the number of forked threads to the number of capabilities, except in some specialized applications.

Also, `getNumCapability` is probably returning `1` for you because that's the default for the RTS `-N` flag.  You should make sure you've compiled with the `-threaded` runtime and that you run with the RTS options `+RTS -N` (with no number, it's set to the number of physical capabilities) or `+RTS -N4` or similar, if you want to run multiple threads in parallel.